# How to traverse when using `cat` command?

Tags: linux, unix, cat

How to travel in the shell using `cat` command? (arrow keys are not working)

```
cat > myfile
```

Comment: what do you mean with "traverse"?

Comment: @fedorqui : Travel forward backward.

Comment: Note that `cat` prints the data, is not like an editor. So you will get all the output in your screen, that is all. Maybe you want to use `less myfile`.

Comment: or a text editor...

Comment: Do you mean scrolling? You may either use Shift + [PgUp | PgDn] or redirect your output to a pager like this: `cat foo | less`.

Comment: Programs that allow to navigate the input usually use the `readline` library to read input, `cat` does not. One way to use readline with arbitrary programs is to use a readline wrapper, e.g. [`rlwrap`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap), should be in the package repositories of most linux distributions.

Comment: Best way to create a file while being able to edit your input is to use an editor, such as `nano` or `vi`.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick : One of my students asked this. He was writing a shell script using cat > file name and typing the code. but when he wants to go back and change some code the arrow keys are not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are asking for a pager. For that you can use `more` or `less` (yes, these are the real names). As an example, you can use `cat FILE | less` or just `less FILE`. In there, you can scroll/search/... (exit with `q`).

Comment: One of my students asked this. He was writing a shell script using cat > file name and typing the code. but when he wants to go back and change some code the arrow keys are not working?

Comment: Ah, for this task I suggest to use an editor: vim, emacs, nano, pico, joe, ...

Comment: Thanks C-Otto, I'll inform him :)